# C# Windows Service process cannot access file exception and service won't wake up after timer ends

Tags: c#, windows, service, timer

I have written a simple service which will contact local MS SQL SERVER database and run query against the database and create a excel and pdf document with the data from MS SQL SERVER. Everything works fine i am facing two major problems.

1. Service won't start after a exception
2. Service cannot access excel file because it be being used by another process to prepare a pdf.

I am using System.Timers.Timer, my code is as below:

```
    private static System.Timers.Timer _aTimer;
      public ReportManagerService()
            {

                _aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(10 * 60 * 1000);

                _aTimer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(_aTimer_Elapsed);

                _aTimer.AutoReset = false;

                _aTimer.Enabled = true;
                InitializeComponent();




            }
      protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
            {


                    _aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(10 * 60 * 1000);//10 minutes   10 * 60 * 1000
                    _aTimer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(_aTimer_Elapsed);

                    _aTimer.AutoReset = false;
                    _aTimer.Enabled = true;


                }
     protected override void OnStop()
            {

                    _aTimer.Enabled = false;
                    _aTimer.Stop();

                }
      void _aTimer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
            {
     try
                {
                    //_aTimer.AutoReset = false;
                    _aTimer.Stop();
    //huge code which may take more than 10 minutes for execution 
//get data from sql server
// export to excel using closedXML
using (XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook(folderpath))
                    {
wb.SaveAs(SaveLocationDirectory + "\\" + ReportName + "_" + tempFilename);
wb.Dispose();
}
//export to pdf

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
                {
    }
     finally
                {
     _aTimer.Start();

    }

    }
```

i want someone to let me know what i am doing wrong, what i believe, happening is timer is resetting before all the code executes and excel workbook is not disposing properly. As I can see EXCEL.EXE Left running in my task manager under processes after the error.

Comment: I would start by debugging your code and find out why an exception is being thrown.

Comment: thank you that cwould be great help